# Inequality assurance

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, summation, proof-writing

Suppose we have $$0<a_{1},a_{2},b_{1},b_{2},c_{1},c_{2},d_{1},d_{2}<1$$ and we know that $$\frac{a_{1}}{b_{1}} > \frac{c_{1}}{d_{1}},$$
$$\frac{a_{2}}{b_{2}} > \frac{c_{2}}{d_{2}}$$

What else we need to prove in order to be sure that:

$$\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}}{b_{1}+b_{2}} > \frac{c_{1}+c_{2}}{d_{1}+d_{2}}?$$

This is just an example. The number of variables might be more albeit obeying the same conditions as mentioned.

In general, I want to prove that:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}} > \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}}?$$

where $$\frac{a_{i}}{b_{i}} > \frac{c_{i}}{d_{i}},$$
$$\forall 1 \le i \le n, \;\;\; n \in \mathbb{N}^{+}$$

---

**EDIT1 (bounty will be awarded for this part)**

Alternatively, we can state the problem as follows:

The (least) necessary conditions we need in order to guarantee that:

$$\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i} x_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}
>
\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \beta_{i} y_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}},$$

where we know that:
$$\alpha_{i} > \beta_{i} > 1,$$
$$\bigg( \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i} \bigg) \in (0,1).$$

---

**EDIT2 (as for the answer to which the bounty is awarded)**

Although the condition suggested by @quasi is a very strong one, I awarded him/er the bounty since his/er answer was the cleanest. My problem remains unsolved, though!

Comment: Is it related to [Stern–Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Brocot_tree) somehow...?

Comment: @CiaPan In my problem, not really.

Answer (score 2):

If the variables $a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2$ are scaled by a positive factor, the values of the fractions being compared will still be the same, hence the condition

$$0 < a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2 < 1$$

can be replaced by the simpler condition

$$a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2 > 0$$

To see that the conditions

$$a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2 > 0$$
$$\frac{a_{1}}{b_{1}} > \frac{c_{1}}{d_{1}},$$
$$\frac{a_{2}}{b_{2}} > \frac{c_{2}}{d_{2}}$$

are not sufficient to force

$$\frac{a_{1}+a_{2}}{b_{1}+b_{2}} > \frac{c_{1}+c_{2}}{d_{1}+d_{2}}$$

let $a_1,b_1,c_1,d_1,a_2,b_2,c_2,d_2$ be given by

$$
a_1 = 1,\;\; b_1 = 2,\;\; c_1 = 3,\;\;d_1 = 7,\;\; 
a_2 = 1,\;\; b_2 = 5,\;\; c_2 = 1,\;\;d_2 = 6
$$

Then

$$\frac{a_1}{b_1} = \frac{1}{2} > \frac{3}{7} = \frac{c_1}{d_1}$$

$$\frac{a_2}{b_2} = \frac{1}{5} > \frac{1}{6} = \frac{c_2}{d_2}$$

$$\text{but}$$

$$
\frac{a_1 + a_2}{b_1 + b_2} 
= \frac{1 + 1}{2 + 5} 
= \frac{2}{7}
< \frac{4}{13}
= \frac{3 + 1}{7 + 6}
= \frac{c_1 + c_2}{d_1 + d_2} 
$$

However, for positive real numbers $x_1,...,x_n$ and $y_1,...,y_n$, we always have

$$
\min\left\{\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right\}
\le \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}}
\le \max \left\{\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right\}
$$

To justify the above claim, let

$$m = \min\left\{\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right\}$$
$$M = \max\left\{\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right\}$$

Then

$$m 
\;\;\le\;\; 
\frac{x_i}{y_i}
\;\;\le\;\;
M\;\;\text{ for all }i$$

$$
\implies\;
my_i 
\;\;\le\;\; 
x_i 
\;\;\le\;\; 
My_i
\;\;\text{ for all }i
\qquad\;\;\;\;
$$

$$
\implies\; m\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i 
 \;\;\le\;\;
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i 
 \;\;\le\;\;
M\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i
\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$

$$
\implies\; m  \;\;\le\;\;  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}}  \;\;\le\;\;  M
\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$

$$
\implies\; 
\min\left\{\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right\}
\;\;\le\;\;
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}}
\;\;\le\;\;
\max \left\{\frac{x_i}{y_i}\right\}
\qquad\qquad\qquad
$$

as claimed.

Thus, for the question at hand, if 
$a_1,...,a_n$ and $b_1,...,b_n$ 
are positive real numbers, the condition

$$\min\left\{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right\} > \max\left\{\frac{c_i}{d_i}\right\}$$

would be sufficient$\,-\,$even without the other conditions, to force

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}} > \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}}$$

since in that case,

$$
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{i}}
\ge
\min\left\{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right\} > \max\left\{\frac{c_i}{d_i}\right\}
\ge
\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}d_{i}}
$$

Comment: @989: I edited in an explanation.

Comment: (+1) Can you provide an evidence for your first claim based on which you deduce the second inequality in your answer?

Comment: You may use `\left\{` and `\right\}` to make the braces automatically adjust their size to the contents.

Comment: @CiaPan: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: @989: Which claim would like to see more support for?

Comment: I know about the counter-example and that's why I stated in my question "what else do we need to prove blah blah". What I meant is this one: `min{.} \le . \le max{.}`. Moreover, do you think that `min{.} > max{.}` is `\iff` or not? I don't think so.

Comment: @989: I'll edit in a justification of min{.} \le . \le max{.} in a little while.

Comment: @989: The condition
$$\min\left\{\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right\} > \max\left\{\frac{c_j}{d_j}\right\}$$
is a sufficient condition, but it's a very strong condtion, and definitely not a necessary conditon.

Comment: So you also do agree with me. In my setting, at least, this strong condition does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

Take the case where $n=2$ then you want to show:$$
\frac{\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2}{x_1+x_2} \gt \frac{\beta_1y_1+\beta_2y_2}{y_1+y_2}
$$ which is equivalent to $$
\alpha_1x_1y_1+\alpha_2x_2y_1+\alpha_1x_1y_2+\alpha_2x_2y_2 \gt \beta_1y_1x_1+\beta_2y_2x_1+\beta_1y_1x_2+\beta_2y_2x_2 \tag{0}
$$ given that $\alpha_1 > \beta_1$ and $\alpha_2>\beta_2$ and matching terms from each side $$
\alpha_1x_1y_1 > \beta_1y_1x_1 \tag{1}
$$$$
\alpha_2x_2y_1 \;?\; \beta_1y_1x_2 \tag{2}
$$$$
\alpha_1x_1y_2 \;?\; \beta_2y_2x_1 \tag{3}
$$$$
\alpha_2x_2y_2 > \beta_2y_2x_2 \tag{4}
$$ (I'm using the symbol $?$ to mean unknown inequality)

As you can see the two unknown inequalities prevent a guarantee of the result you want. Specifically, if the LHS of (2) and (3) is sufficiently smaller than the RHS.

There are a couple of ways to "satisfy" the inequality (0):

1. Require $\alpha_2 > \beta_1$ and $\alpha_1 > \beta_2$
2. Require $\alpha_1x_1y_1 - \beta_1y_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2y_2 - \beta_2y_2x_2 > \beta_1y_1x_2 - \alpha_2x_2y_1 + \beta_2y_2x_1 - \alpha_1x_1y_2$

Extrapolating to the full problem, #1 means $min(\alpha_i) > max(\beta_j)$, which sounds like a stronger condition than what you want. On the other hand #2 is almost as bad as just requiring a precondition that is the result you want to guarantee. Not quite as bad, since the actual condition is: $$ \sum_{i=1}^n{(\alpha_i-\beta_i)x_iy_i} > \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^n{(\beta_j-\alpha_i)x_iy_j} \tag{5}
$$

This is the minimal condition (if relying on your input data can be specified as part of your conditions).

Comment: (+1) Thanks but (I think) If we can assure this, we wouldn't have had the stated problem. I mean for this, we need really detailed information.

Comment: Makes sense. Unfortunately (5) is the least necessary condition. So you'll have to either modify the statement of the problem (for example to not "need really detailed information") or accept a stronger than least condition. I suggest you edit the OP to make clear what your additional constraints on the conditions are. BTW the absolute value you edited in is not necessary (and makes the condition stronger than it needs to be). If, for example, $\beta1y_1x_2 - \alpha_2y_1x_2$ is negative then that difference "helps" you achieve the desired inequality.